ggplot2: Circular barplot manipulation for scalability
Preamble:
I recently having this thread
Goal
Replicating this plot

Current code
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
  values = c(88, 61, 56, 77, 83, 63, 42, 60)
) %>%
  mutate(
    bar_color = case_when(
      values < 62 ~ "#f2452e",
      values < 85 ~ "#76c5d0",
      values >= 85 ~ "#4b7d84",
    )
  )

ggplot(data, aes(x = labels, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = bar_color),
           stat = "identity", size = 1,
           color = "gray20", width = 1,
           alpha = 0.8) +
  coord_polar(start = -(pi / 8)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = c("transparent", alpha("grey80", 0.5))
    ),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 96.5,
             color = "grey90", size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 95, 5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5:8.5, y = 0, yend = 95),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, color = alpha("grey20", 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 94,
             color = "grey20", size = 1) +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels, y = 96), fill = "white", size = 6)

Current plot:

Problem
The value of:

breaks in scale_y_continuous()
yintercept in geom_hline()
yend in geom_segment(); and
y in geom_label()

Is all hardcoded. It become challenge when data$values changing, especially above 95 (max is 100). I need help on making sure that the values of problem #1 to #4 stays at around 100 to cover all possible values of data$values
Example of issue
I change the value of above's parameters to around 99-100 because i want to make the length of bar relative to 0 - 100.

breaks = seq(0, 100, 5)
yintercept = 101.5 in the first
yintercept = 99 in the second geom_hline()
yend = 100 in geom_segment(); and
y = 101 in geom_label()

so become this:
ggplot(data, aes(x = labels, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = bar_color),
           stat = "identity", size = 1,
           color = "gray20", width = 1,
           alpha = 0.8) +
  coord_polar(start = -(pi / 8)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = c("transparent", alpha("grey80", 0.5))
    ),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 101.5,
             color = "grey90", size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5:8.5, y = 0, yend = 100),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, color = alpha("grey20", 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 99,
             color = "grey20", size = 1) +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels, y = 101), fill = "white", size = 6)

New result is like this:
Notice that theres extra circle in the outer line and i kinda struggle with this


I think the answer is already within your question :)
You can use a variable that will be of form y_hline <- max(data$values) + 6
and then use it in geom_hline(yintercept = y_hline, color = "grey20", size = 1)
Of course you may add a value that is computed based on data$values
Same for all other hard coded values

Basically in geom_bar() with coord_polar(),  it should be following the max value? Because when i set the yintercept into, let's say, 101 to cover max value, the plot become really messy

I would do away with a background grid altogether and draw the breaks yourself. It is not clear from your question whether you want to normalize the values so that the maximum value is always at 100. If so, you would do:
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
                   values = c(88, 61, 56, 77, 83, 63, 42, 60)) %>%
        mutate(bar_color = case_when(values < 62 ~ "#de583f",
                                     values < 85 ~ "#759d9f",
                                     values >= 85 ~ "#4b7d84",))

scaling_factor <- max(data$values)

ggplot(data %>% mutate(values = values / scaling_factor), 
       aes(labels, values, fill = bar_color)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, aes(color = after_scale(fill))) +
  annotate("linerange", ymin = 0, ymax = 1, x = seq(nrow(data)) - 0.5,
           color = "#494949") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8) / 10, color = "#494949", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.02, color = "#d9d9d9", linewidth = 4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, color = "#494949") +
  geom_label(aes(y = 1, label = labels), fill = "#edecea", color = "#494949",
             size = 8, family = "Courier New") +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_polar(start = -pi/8) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#edecea", color = NA))


If the numbers are absolute values and you want the range of your plot to be 100, just change the line scaling_factor <- max(data$values) to scaling_factor <- 100. Then the exact same plotting code will give you:


Hi @Allan_Cameron, thanks for your answer. Sorry for unclean question.
This is exactly what I mean: the bar length relative to 0 - 100, or in this case, 0-1. Since i don't really mind with the y axis number, converting it to 0-1 is very helpful i think. Also your code is much more easier to reverse engineer. Moreover, extra decoration makes this very beautiful.Thanks a lot!

Putting my comment as an answer to be more explicit.

extract the max value from data$values
use it inside the plot section to tune the different layers of your list

I also:

replaced size by linewidth in geom_hline as it will throw deprecation warnings
removed a few extra ',' right before some ')'


Here is the result:

library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
  values = c(88, 61, 56, 77, 83, 63, 42, 98)
) %>%
  mutate(
    bar_color = case_when(
      values < 62 ~ "#f2452e",
      values < 85 ~ "#76c5d0",
      values >= 85 ~ "#4b7d84"))

ymax <- max(data$values)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = labels, y = values)) +

     geom_bar(aes(fill = bar_color),
           stat = "identity", size = 1,
           color = "gray20", width = 1,
           alpha = 0.8) +

     coord_polar(start = -(pi / 8)) +   scale_fill_identity() +

     theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(
      linewidth = .8,
      color = c("transparent", alpha("grey80", 0.5))),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank()) +

     geom_hline(yintercept = ymax + 8.5,
             color = "grey90", linewidth = 3) +

     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, ymax + 7, 5)) +

     geom_segment(aes(x = 1.5:8.5, y = 0, yend = ymax + 7),
               inherit.aes = FALSE, color = alpha("grey20", 0.5)) +

     geom_hline(yintercept = ymax + 6,
             color = "grey20", linewidth = 1) +

     geom_label(aes(label = labels, y = ymax + 8), fill = "white", size = 6)

print(p)

And the result:


In your case, if the max value is 66, then the geom_hline, will still very close to the bar.
I mean it will be best for me to make sure the geom_hline at the 100th value so the bar length will be shown relative to 0 - 100 score.
I've tried to set those parameters to value from 99-100, the plot becomes really messy. I'll edit my question
